# How do I extend Javas JFrame to replicate WinForms' ShowDialog (.Net Framework)?

Tags: java, c#, .net, winforms, swing

I have written an application in Java that has a JFrame with options. I now want a certain action to be executed when the user has confirmed the dialog with "Ok". I was recommended to add a return value to JFrame.

Unfortunately, I don't have any experience and need some help. Here are the details.

I want to extend JFrame so that I can have an Enum "DialogResult" when closing a JFrame like in the .Net Framework. Well, the Enum is no problem. My problem is to replicate the ShowDialog method from WinForms of the .Net Framework working in Java for the class JFrame.

Below is an example code in C#:

```
// DlgOptions : Form
DlgOptions dlg = new DlgOptions();
if(dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Ok)
{
    // do something only when "Ok" was clicked
}
```

Here's a link from MSDN with the behavior I want to replicate:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx

How can I best implement this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I changed my DlgOptions class so it doesn't extend JFrame but JDialog. I also added an enumeration DialogResult and added a public property of this type in my DlgOptions. But I still have a problem. When I use this code:

```
// executed when user clicked a JMenuItem in a JMenuBar
DlgOptions dlg = new DlgOptions();
dlg.setModal(true);
dlg.setVisible(true);

if(dlg.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // do something
}
```

the program continues running *before* the user closed the modal dialog. What can I do?

**EDIT 2:**

My JDialog contains two JButtons; one to confirm changes that were made and one to abort changing the preferences for the program. I have several JCheckBoxes the user can check or uncheck.

So a JOptionPane would not be what I want / need (as far as I know). That's why I need a modal JDialog. But my Java code above doesn't work as I want it to. I read on a German website of a Java book that a JDialog set to modal with

```
setModal(true);
```

would cause the program to wait until the dialog is closed. The problem is, that the code continues too early.

Comment: See: [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Comment: Thanks. I used JDialog but still have a problem. Please see my edit.

Comment: Whats wrong with using a JOptionPane? In any case post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have updated my question. A JOptionPane is as I understand it correctly some kind of MessageBox as in .Net. But I need something else. Please see my second edit for more details.

Comment: That is NOT an `MCVE`. We can't compile/execute/test that code. So all you need is a JFrame with a button to display your JDialog. On the dialog all you need is a simple button to close the dialog, to learn the basic concept of using a modal dialog. Total code will be about 20 lines of code. Simplify the code when learning a new concept. All the code related to foreground/background/font is completely irrelevant to learning about the modal concept.

Comment: I reduced my question to the relevant information. My apologies for too much code / text.

Comment: No, that is NOT an `MCVE`. How is that a "complete and verifiable" example? How do we compile and execute that? Did you not read my comment about what is required?